PrimeNG, InputOtp -- Numeric keypad not working when InputOtp has [integerOnly]="true"
In PrimeNG, InputOtp
When we providing [integerOnly]="true", numeric pad (right side of the keybord) is not working.
Note: Num Lock is Off
<div class="card flex justify-content-center">
    <p-inputOtp [(ngModel)]="value" [integerOnly]="true"></p-inputOtp>
</div>

export class InputOtpIntegerOnlyDemo {
    value : any
}



Num lock off, these buttons wont work, enable it!

What is the image for?

Image is for reference, which side of number pad is not working,

<div class="card flex justify-content-center">
    <p-inputOtp [(ngModel)]="value" [integerOnly]="true" (keydown)="onKeyDown($event)"></p-inputOtp>
</div>

In your component class:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'input-otp-integer-only-demo',
    templateUrl: './input-otp-integer-only-demo.html'
})
export class InputOtpIntegerOnlyDemo {
    value: any;

    onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
        // Allow only numeric keypad inputs
        if (
            (event.key === '0' || event.key === '1' || event.key === '2' ||
            event.key === '3' || event.key === '4' || event.key === '5' ||
            event.key === '6' || event.key === '7' || event.key === '8' ||
            event.key === '9' || event.key === 'Tab' || event.key === 'Backspace' ||
            event.key === 'Delete' || event.key === 'ArrowLeft' || event.key === 'ArrowRight') &&
            !event.ctrlKey && !event.altKey && !event.metaKey
        ) {
            // Allow the key press
            return;
        }

        // Prevent the default behavior for other keys
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}

